# Where does Steam store Fallout Shelter's save files?

Tags: steam, fallout-shelter

Now that Fallout Shelter has released on Steam I would like to use my save-files off the Bethesda launcher function. I already copied the save-files of the Bethesda launcher and have them on my PC. However I am unable to locate where the save files are for the Steam function. Anyone can tell me?

Comment: Most games store in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common`

Comment: The games I know, it is the savefiles im looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the Steam version your saves are under : 
`C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\FalloutShelter`.

To access it press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type %localappdata%, press enter. Then browse to the `FalloutShelter` directory.

Your saves are like `VaultX.sav` and `VaultX.sav.bkp`.