# My vault just deleted itself, can I get it back?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was playing the game and it suddenly crashed. I got back on and my vault had deleted itself, how do I get it back? I was playing on pc with Steam.

Comment: See if your saves are still there, more on where they are: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304811/fallout-shelter-move-save-files

Comment: If you're on android, you can download a fallout shelter editor and just re-create your vault from scratch.

Comment: ok, I found my saves but I do not know how to use them to get my vault back. Do you Know?